# Golang strict nil checks

Tags: go

In TypeScript, if I enable strict null checks, I get a nice warning any time I try to access a property of a possibly null value like so:

[image: Typescript strict null check example]

I notice that in Go, if I do the same thing for a pointer, I do not get a warning.

I would like to know, is there some way I can set up Go so that I get compiler errors when I do the equivalent. For example, I would like the following code in go to complain:

```golang
var someUUID *uuid.UUID

fmt.Println(someUUID.String())
```

And then it should stop complaining if I do this:

```golang
var someUUID *uuid.UUID

if someUUID != nil {
  fmt.Println(someUUID.String())
}
```

Comment: Go's compiler is not capable of doing that.

Comment: `nil` is a valid value in Go, and can even be a valid method receiver value. You get a panic if you attempt dereference it, but there's very few useful times that this could be determined statically from the source. There may be some linters that can more analysis, but the compiler specifically does not emit warnings.

Comment: Note that in Go, a nil receiver is a valid value. You can write methods that handle nil receivers. So such a warning would be wrong in some cases.

Comment: `nil` receiver is not only valid, it's required in many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strict null checking as it exists in TS is based upon a foundation that includes fundamental differences between TypeScript and Go. If you [read about TS' strict null checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks), there isn't even a conceptual equivalent in Go:

> In strict null checking mode, the `null` and `undefined` values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and `any`.

In TS (like in JS), all objects are references which can be `null`; turning on strict null checking effectively disables that behavior, making `null` a separate type that's not assignable to object types.

In Go, only pointers and pointer-based types can be `nil`, and there is no way you could toggle that behavior off to say that they can't be `nil`. There is no `any` type in Go that *could* contain `nil` if you did so. There are no combined types like `T | nil` that would allow you to accept a possibly-`nil` value.

Furthermore, as several commenters pointed out, in Go (unlike in TS), you can still call methods on `nil` pointers, and that is not inherently "wrong" behavior. You will not encounter a `nil dereference` error until you try to dereference the pointer (typically implicitly by accessing a field). So strict checking of this kind would break live Go code and force changes in Go idioms, including things like "usable zero values".